# Customizing Devise's default URLs: Remove "/new" and "/edit" and set an alternate URL Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I customize the URLs that Devise uses by default? My goal is to remove `/new`, `/edit` and other parts, or set it to use another URL instead. For example, instead of `/users/sign_up/new`, I want it to just be `/users/sign_up` without the `/new`.

Delete the `/new` and `/edit` and change that same url so as not to affect the project at all.

Answer (score 1):

To customize default Devise paths you can use `devise_for` method in `routes.rb`

You can pass `:path_names` keyword argument and configure different path names to overwrite defaults `:sign_in`, `:sign_out`, `:sign_up`, `:password`, `:confirmation`, `:unlock`

```rb
devise_for :users, path_names: {
  sign_in: 'login',
  sign_up: 'sign_up',
  sign_out: 'logout',
  password: 'secret',
  confirmation: 'verification',
  edit: 'edit/profile',
}
```

Read more in [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for#label-Options)

Comment: Ok, I already have that, but I want to remove the /new or change to another address

Comment: To change use `:sign_up` key

Comment: Look I have this problem now, make a change of URL for editing the profile:
`  devise_scope :user do
    get "/conf" => "devise/registrations#edit", as: "edit_user_registration" 
    put "/conf" => "devise/registrations#update" 
  end`
But when there is an error or because of a wrong password or something else, it takes me directly to sign_up, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Look, I was also trying to do all the routes manually, but I get an error
Manual routes:
[Manual routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zoua.jpg)

Comment: But I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvSkB.jpg)

Comment: How to replace all the routes manually but I have the above mentioned error. And I do not know what to do

Comment: You didn't use `path_names` as documentation recommends

Comment: I use path names, but to make sign_up/edit just /config instead